# how to calculate how high would a helium balloon with weight go?

Tags: pressure, atmospheric-science, density, buoyancy, gas

I knew that one liter of helium would lift approximately 1 gram of mass. However, I could not find how to calculate how high would that 1 gram go. Imagine if we have a helium balloon (ignore the weight of the balloon skin and string linking the balloon to the mass) lifting a gram of mass, how high would that balloon go? Is there a formula to relate the mass of the object and the height a helium balloon that can provide the lift force exactly equal to the system's weight?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to calculate but it is very unreliable. The reason being the density of atmosphere at different places and heights varies thereby changing the buoyant force on the apparatus.
However to calculate the height we can do this.
Measure the total mass of the apparatus( you may include the balloon and string too).
Find out total volume it occupies.
Divide mass by volume to get effective density.
You'll notice it is far less than current density of air around( thats what makes it rise).
You just need to find that height where the density of air around is equal to that effective density of apparatus. Now this becomes a problem of earth's topology not a physics question.

Comment: Why do you assume that the effective density of the balloon is constant?